# Proof of $(\mu*1)=\delta_1$ where $(f*g)$ is Dirichlet Convolution

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, mobius-function, dirichlet-convolution, kronecker-delta

I was interested in the proof for this fact because it is used to prove M$\ddot o$bius Inversion Formula. However, I did not completely understand how [proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_M%C3%B6bius_Function_over_Divisors/Lemma) used a series of binomial coefficients to prove the fact. So I tried to find another proof.

$\mathrm Objective$: Prove $$(\mu*1)=\delta_1$$ using $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$ and $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}$$

$\mathrm Work$: $$\zeta(s)\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{k^s}$$
$$1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(k)}{n^sk^s}$$
Let $m=nk$
$$1=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{nk=m} \frac{\mu(k)}{m^s}$$
$$1=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{\mu*1}{n^s}$$
So $$(\mu*1)= 1, n=1$$
And $$(\mu*1)= 0, n\neq1$$
Which is the definition of Kronecker Delta $\delta_1$.

$\mathrm Question$:Was my work valid? I am still in high school so I doubt that my calculus teacher can help me.

Comment: Depends. Can you justify the reordering of the series? Have you a uniqueness theorem for the coefficients of Dirichlet series? If both answers are "yes", then it's valid, but it would be better to at least mention the justifications.

Comment: Wouldn't the reordering of the series be just  a property of Summation? And what do you mean by uniqueness of the coefficients?

Comment: No, [we cannot always reorder ad libitum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_rearrangement_theorem). By uniqueness of the coefficients, I mean that $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{b_n}{n^s}$$ for all $s$ with $\operatorname{Re} s > s_0$ implies $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah I see, much thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Never doubt your Calculus teacher.*

Jokes apart, your work is fine, but let us recall a few facts for future reference, too.

**Definition**. A function $f:\mathbb{N}^+\to\mathbb{C}$ is said to be *multiplicative* if $\gcd(n,m)=1$ ensures $f(n)\,f(m)=f(nm)$. *Completely (or totally) multiplicative* if $f(n)\,f(m)=f(mn)$ holds in any case.

**Lemma**. The values of a multiplicative function are fixed by the values that such function attains over prime powers, by the fundamental theorem of Arithmetics ($\mathbb{Z}$ is a $\text{UFD}$).

**Definition**. The Dirichlet convolution/multiplicative convolution between two arithmetic functions is defined through $(f*g)(n)=\sum_{d \mid n}f(d)\,g\left(\tfrac{n}{d}\right)$. The operator $*$ is both associative and commutative, and the convolution between two multiplicative functions still is a multiplicative function.

**Definition**. Any multiplicative function $\chi$ is associated with a *Dirichlet L-function* 
$$ L(\chi,s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s} $$
and assuming that $\chi$ takes values in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leq 1\}$ the last series is absolutely convergent over the region $\text{Re}\, s>1$. The region of conditional convergence might be larger, depending on $\chi$.

**Lemma**. We have the formal identity
$$ L(f*g,s) = L(f,s)\cdot L(g,s) $$
which is an actual identity over the region $\text{Re}\,s>1$.

**Theorem** (Euler's product). For any $s$ such that $\text{Re}\,s>1$ we have:
$$ L(\chi,s) = \prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}+\frac{\chi(p^2)}{p^{2s}}+\frac{\chi(p^3)}{p^{3s}}+\ldots\right)$$
which simplifies into
$$ L(\chi,s) = \prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}\right)^{-1} $$
if $\chi$ is completely multiplicative.

**Theorem** (Principle of analytic continuation). If $L(\chi_1,s)=L(\chi_2,s)$ holds over some region of the form $\text{Re}\,s>c$, then $\chi_1\equiv \chi_2$. This can be proved by applying $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ (the inverse Laplace transform) to both sides, then by invoking the principle of analytic continuation in its standard form.

---

Given this wonderful intro, we are ready to give two proofs of the Moebius inversion formula.
We recall that $\mu(n)$ differs from zero iff $n$ is a square-free integer, and in such a case it equals $(-1)^{\omega(n)}$, i.e. $\pm 1$ according to the parity of the number of prime divisors of $n$. $\mu(n)$ is obviously a multiplicative function, like the function which constantly equals one. By the machinery above, in order to prove $\mu * 1 = \delta_1$ it is enough to prove $L(\mu,s)\cdot L(1,s) = L(\delta_1,s)=1 $ for any $s$ with a large enough real part. On the other hand such identity is trivial by Euler's product, since

$$ L(\mu,s)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right),\qquad L(1,s)=\zeta(s)=\prod_{p}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}.$$
This works like a charm, but it is definitely an overkill. Since $\mu*1$ is a multiplicative function, in order to prove $\mu*1=\delta_1$ it is enough to show that $(\mu*1)(p^k)=0$ holds for any prime $p$ and any exponent $k\geq 1$. By definition of $*$ we have

$$ (\mu*1)(p^k) = \sum_{d\mid p^k} \mu(d) = \sum_{h=0}^{1}\mu(p^h) = 1-1 = 0 $$
and we are equally done.

Comment: Amazing, you cover all the bases for the proof. You really went overboard haha. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to answer my question.